# how to know where we are in a loop using php

Tags: php

I met some trouble with a loop, for doing some xml files for withdrawal
I have to assign a value to each record (sepa)
The first record must be called and set 'FIRST',
the nexts must be called and set 'RECURRENT',
and the last one must be called and set 'FINAL'

for doing that I do a loop that insert into my database the reord that will be set into the xml file.

for the first, I have no problem, for the recurrents, I also have no problem, but I do not know how to know when the record is the last of my loop, so I can set 'FINAL'

below is my code

```
 $i=0;
    while ($prlvt = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5)):
    if($i==0){
        $statement = 'FIRST';
    }elseif($i>0){
        $statement = 'RECURRENT';
    }
    $prlvt_rqt = "INSERT INTO `prelevements` SET
`prelevements__n_doss` = '{$_GET['n_doss']}', 
`prelevements__statut` = 0, 
`prelevements__date_record` = '{$prlvt['date_action']}', 
`prelevements__montant` = '{$prlvt['description']}',
`prelevements__statement` = '{$statement}'
";
    mysql_query($prlvt_rqt);
    $i++;

    endwhile;
```

The trouble is that I do not know how to set my 'FINAL' statement.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `if ($i == mysql_num_rows($result5)) {// last item}`

Comment: You should consider using `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`. `mysql_*` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [documentation of `mysql_num_rows`](http://at.php.net/mysql_num_rows):

```
if($i==0){
    $statement = 'FIRST';
}elseif($i == mysql_num_rows($result5) - 1){
    $statement = 'FINAL';
}else{
    $statement = 'RECURENT';
}
```

Consider swichting to `mysqli_*`, as of PHP 5.5.0 `mysql_*` will be deprecated.

Comment: For the OP: Notice the "Warning" sign on the `mysql_num_rows` documentation, stating that `mysql_*` is officially deprecated starting with PHP 5.5

Answer (score 3):

You could get the total number of items mysql_num_rows()

```
$i=0;
$tot = mysql_num_rows($result5);
while ($prlvt = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5)):

if ($i==0) $statement = 'FIRST';
elseif($i == ($tot-1)) $statement = 'LAST';
else $statment = 'RECURRENT';

// rest of your code
$i++;
endwhile;
```

Apart from this I would strongly suggest you to switch method to PDO as the old statements are now obsolete and potentially vulnerable

Answer (score 3):

The best is to use `mysql_num_rows` in your case. But as alternative in cases when you can't add `if` you can do:

```
while(/*..*/){
}
mysql_query('UPDATE prelevements SET statmet = "FINAL" WHERE id = '.mysql_insert_id();
```

BUT

- Use answer with `mysql_num_rows`
- Use `PDO` or `Mysqli` instead of `Mysql`

Answer (score 1):

```
$i=0;
while ($prlvt = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5)):
if($i==0){
    $statement = 'FIRST';

}elseif($i == mysql_num_rows($result5)){
$statement = 'FINAL';
 }elseif($i>0){
    $statement = 'RECURRENT';
}
$prlvt_rqt = "INSERT INTO `prelevements` SET
`prelevements__n_doss` = '{$_GET['n_doss']}', 
`prelevements__statut` = 0,
`prelevements__date_record` = '{$prlvt['date_action']}',
`prelevements__montant` = '{$prlvt['description']}',



`prelevements__statement` = '{$statement}'
";



 mysql_query($prlvt_rqt);
$i++;

endwhile;
```

This is the full solution.